# Google nearby Api shutdown

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am working on creating a proximity platform for my clients.
Where clients receive push notifications on their mobiles.
I hear that Google is shutting down their google nearby api.
I was also told that google connections & messages perform the same functions, kind of defeats the purpose of shutting down nearby if there is an alternative route. Is this true?

Thanks

Comment: So far from the [Google Nearby documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/), they haven't disclosed any announcement yet.

Comment: If you're referring to this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html, it's specifically about Nearby Notifications, which seems was a sub-project of Nearby API. Nearby API seems to still exist.

Answer (score -1):

It is true but developers can still push proximity based notifications in their own apps using Proximity Beacons API.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html

Comment: The article is specifically about Nearby Notifications, which isn't the entire Nearby API.